# How to force EditText to accept only numbers in compose kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, textfield

How to force outLineTxtFieldValue to accept only numbers ?.

**For example**,

user can only enter numbers, not a negative value. We can enter numbers such as

`120`,
`1`,
`9`,
`10012`,

in short, we can say `positive integers`  or  `natural numbers` in kotlin compose `outlinetextfield` or `textfield`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TextField(
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number)
```

Comment: thanks it works but when I enter string value app crashed. How can I check this in viewmodel. for example if user enter string value I dont want to crash app instead of shows toast message like that.

Answer (score 0):

Simply display the keyboard with only numbers:

```
TextField(
     value = textState,
     onValueChange = { text ->
         textState = text
     },
     keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
         keyboardType = KeyboardType.NumberPassword
     ),
     visualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None
)
```